# Tried to call Provider.of<dynamic>. This is likely a mistake and is therefore unsupported

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-provider

Trying to get and text current user's uid but facing the error with Provider implementation.

> Tried to call Provider.of. This is likely a mistake and is
> therefore unsupported. If you want to expose a variable that can be
> anything, consider changing `dynamic` to `Object` instead.
> 'package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 307 pos
> 7: 'T != dynamic'

Here's the code where provider is used

```
 return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
              future: Provider.of(context, listen: false).auth.getCurrentUid(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.data}");
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
```

function to get current uid

```
//GET UID
  Future<String> getCurrentUid() async {
    return _auth.currentUser.uid;
  }
```

How can i fix this?
Really appreciate any help!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Just replace

```
future: Provider.of(context, listen: false).auth.getCurrentUid(),
```

with

```
future: Provider.of<YOUR_PROVIDER_CLASSNAME>(context, listen: false).auth.getCurrentUid(),
```

and your should be fine.

The only moment you can use `Provider.of` without specifying the Class that should be provided, is when you're initializing a variable of your provider.

```
MyProvider _myProvider = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just tell the provider which type of "Provider" class is it.

```
future: Provider.of<CLASSNAME>(context, listen: false).auth.getCurrentUid(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, the fixed by adding the (Provider Class/ change notifire class) to the provider list which I forgot :). In my case, my provider class was "Counter".

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ///mocking the providers
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```