# Assertion failed: C:\…\src\provider.dart:330 T == dynamic "Tried to call Provider.of<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

i keep getting this error..I am using latest version of flutter ,dart,and provider 6.0.2...even if just try to pass a string i get this error..

> Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
> The following assertion was thrown building Homepage(dirty):
> Assertion failed:
> C:\…\src\provider.dart:330
> T == dynamic
> "Tried to call Provider.of. This is likely a mistake and is therefore\nunsupported.\n\nIf you want to expose a variable that can be anything, consider changing\n`dynamic` to `Object` instead.\n"

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: your question answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67063814/tried-to-call-provider-ofdynamic-this-is-likely-a-mistake-and-is-therefore-un

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code this may help according to the above-mentioned Provider.

`future: Provider.of<CLASSNAME>(context, listen: false).auth.getCurrentUid(),`